AWS Cognito Hosted UI is blank page after building with Terraform
I am new to Cognito and hope I'm not missing something obvious here. I tried created a user pool and hosted UI via Terraform. Upon creation, the hosted UI is completely blank. Auditing the network calls reveals several failed GET requests for resources.
Minimal example:
# main.tf

provider "aws" {
  region = "us-west-1"
}

resource "aws_cognito_user_pool" "user_pool" {
  name = "user-pool"
  username_attributes = ["email"]
  
  password_policy {
    minimum_length    = 7
    require_lowercase = true
    require_numbers   = true
    require_symbols   = true
    require_uppercase = true
    temporary_password_validity_days = 7
  }

  device_configuration {
    challenge_required_on_new_device = true
  }
  
  verification_message_template {
    default_email_option = "CONFIRM_WITH_CODE"
  }

  email_configuration {
    reply_to_email_address = "companybi@companyco.com"
  }

  schema {
    name     = "email"
    attribute_data_type = "String"
    required = true
    mutable  = false
  }
}

resource "aws_cognito_user_pool_domain" "hosted_ui" {
  domain       = "companybi-auth"
  user_pool_id = aws_cognito_user_pool.user_pool.id
}

data "aws_region" "current" {}

output "user_pool_id" {
  value = aws_cognito_user_pool.user_pool.id
}

output "hosted_ui_url" {
  value = "https://${aws_cognito_user_pool_domain.hosted_ui.domain}.auth.${data.aws_region.current.name}.amazoncognito.com/"
}

Errors on the frontend:
(404) GET https://companybi-auth.auth.us-west-1.amazoncognito.com/null/null/css/bootstrap.min.css
(404) GET https://companybi-auth.auth.us-west-1.amazoncognito.com/null/null/css/cognito-login.css
(404) GET https://companybi-auth.auth.us-west-1.amazoncognito.com/null/null/js/amazon-cognito-advanced-security-data.min.js
(404) GET https://companybi-auth.auth.us-west-1.amazoncognito.com/null/null/js/jquery-3.5.1.min.js

Screenshot of the UI:

I understand 404 is standardized to NOT FOUND for resources. I guess I assumed the frontend would be dynamically built by AWS in order to satisfy the requirements configured by the attached user pool. Is there more to it?
The goal is to make this frontend UI correctly load a login form.

null in the errors on frontend is intended? You just anonymized?

Not sure what the goal is, but you can try with something like: aws_cognito_user_pool_domain.hosted_ui.cloudfront_distribution to get the URL.

@MarkoE I guess I expected a zero-config UI to be built based on the login requirements of the user pool. When I build the given user pool and visit the domain, the UI is a blank white screen. Not very good for logging in.

Does this help?

@MarkoE, it does thank you. Turns out, I needed to build an aws_cognito_user_pool_client as well. Also, https://companybi-auth.auth.us-west-1.amazoncognito.com/ is a blank page while https://companybi-auth.auth.us-west-1.amazoncognito.com/login is not.

Based on your comment, @mrchadmwood, it would appear the missing code would be something like :
resource "aws_cognito_user_pool_client" "client" {
  name = "client"

  user_pool_id = aws_cognito_user_pool.user_pool.id
  generate_secret = true
  allowed_oauth_flows_user_pool_client = true
  allowed_oauth_flows = ["code"]
  allowed_oauth_scopes = ["email", "openid", "profile"]
  supported_identity_providers = ["COGNITO"]
  callback_urls = ["https://example.com"] # One could add a local dev url like http://localhost:5001 during local dev phase for local testing only. In which case, you'd need to change the indexing in your output below
  logout_urls = ["https://example.com"]

}

output "hosted_ui_url" {
  value = "https://${aws_cognito_user_pool_domain.hosted_ui.domain}/login?response_type=code&client_id=${aws_cognito_user_pool_client.client.id}&redirect_uri=${aws_cognito_user_pool_client.client.callback_urls[0]}"
}

See: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/cognito_user_pool_client#create-a-user-pool-client-with-cognito-as-the-identity-provider for canonical reference
